# Show image from URL in Keyboard App Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on keyboard app,I am trying to show image from url in the extension but code not working though this code is working fine for my iphone app

```
UIImageView * kanyeGifImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
        NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"some image url"]];
        if ( data == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
            kanyeGifImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
            tempImage = kanyeGifImage.image;
       // kanyeGifImage.image = [self squareImageFromImage:cell.appImageView.image scaledToSize:320];

        });
    });
```

Comment: Did you select "Allow Full Access" on the keyboard settings? Otherwise you won't be able to access the web.

Comment: yes allow Full Access is selected too

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the NSURL is not a web url, but a reference to a file in your bundle.  Bundles are not by default shared between your main app and your extension.  Read up on the section "Sharing Data with your Containing App" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html